# Ubuntu 21.10 - Switching primary screen to external screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xrandr

you just finished installing Ubuntu on my Windows laptop. everything seems to work perfectly. but I am facing a problem when booting, my main screen is switched to my external screen instead of my laptop screen.

Is there a way that I can set my laptop screen as primary?

btw I have an Nvidia graphics card.

EDIT: updating from Settings > Displays works, but resets on reboot

Comment: Settings > Screens. Adjust as intended.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in my question. sure... that works but after a restart, it resets to the external screen. Is there any other way?